# How to mock this inside object

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I have code like this

```
String str = message.getMBC()
            .values()
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .getId();
```

where getMBC() returns a LinkedHashMap with key String and value is some ObjectA.

I am writing a test case where the str is used in some logic. I just want to mock this message to return me a string value without dealing of all the internal complications of linkedhashmap etc.

I tried this in my testcase where message is a mock object.

```
when (message.getMBC()).get(anyObject()).getId()).thenReturn("STRING");
```

I know i am not doing it right as getMBC() should be mock too.

What is the easiest way to mock this object?

Answer (score 0):

Like Below code you can mock inner objects step by step.

```
Message mockMessage = mock(Messsage.class);
when(mockMessage.getMBC()).thenReturn("AnyObject");
AnyObject mockAnyObject = mock(AnyObject.class);
when(mockAnyObject.getId()).thenReturn("STRING");
```

Try with above way to mock all objects

Answer (score 0):

Wrong approach. You don't mock maps. End of story.

Meaning: any kind of collection is just that: a collection of objects. Whenever you think about mocking a **container** you are most likely doing something wrong.

You see, mocking is a powerful tool, that ideally you never use. You really only use it when there is no better way to test your stuff.

Beyond that: you should really understand what your tests are doing. So instead of going `when(x.get(any())).thenReturn(y)` you should very much prefer to simply have a distinct map that contains **exactly** those values you need for your test. `any()` says: "I don't know what params will be used". But you probably should know that.

So, long story short: (if at all), you should only mock the `message` object to return a **customized** map instance upon calls to `getMBC()`. Your approach adds "mocking complexity" to your tests. That leads to tight coupling of your test to implementation details. For no good reasons.